# Converting a byte array to string and vice versa in C#

Tags: c#

I want to convert a byte array to string and then back it into byte array. My Code is:

```
byte[] data = { 250, 15, 1, 220, 127 };
var s = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
var b = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);
```

However, data and b are not equal after running the code, i also tried UTF7,UTF8,UTF32 and ASCII Encoding. None of them worked properly. The only option that works is Default Encoding. As I know it can be varied from one system to another, So how can I EXPLICITLY define the encoding for my problem?

Comment: Define `worked properly`. There's nothing wrong with the conversions as long as you use the *correct* encoding. What are those bytes supposed to contain? It's definitely not ASCII and most likely *not* any of the Unicode codepages

Comment: A given set of bytes doesn't necessarily always translate into a string, at least not one that will go back to the same set of bytes.  This feels like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: worked properly means that the variables "data" and "b" are equal

Comment: Congratulations, you've noticed that Extended ASCII characters don't have the same meaning on every system.  The solution to this is to not use strings to store numeric data, and if your data really is a string of characters, to use a portable Unicode encoding, not Extended ASCII.

Comment: @HamidReza no it doesn't. Worked properly means that if you pass the bytes for a UTF8 string to `UTF8.GetString()` you'll get back the correct string. If you use the *wrong* encoding though, you'll get the wrong response

Comment: @HamidReza if you use the wrong encoding or codepage, eg Russian when the bytes came from a Chinese codepage the results will be garbage or even lost and replaced with the `?` character

Comment: `var s = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250).GetString(data);var b = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250).GetBytes(s);` Put any Windows code page instead of `1250`

Comment: @HamidReza are you trying to *serialize binary data* perhaps? In this case you should use a binary encoding like [Convert.ToBase64String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @James Thorpe  OK. Maybe such kind of XY Problem. do you have any suggestion for doing this? I need to convert my byte array into string and back it again

Comment: @HamidReza You can only convert a byte array into a string _if you already know what the encoding is_.  If you don't, you're probably trying to do something the hard way.  Why do you think you need to convert it to a string and back in the first place?

Comment: @HamidReza doing *what* ? `I need to convert my byte array into string and back it again` isn't a question. There are thousands of ways you could do that. If you wanted to send binary data to a web service or attach data to an email though, there are standardized ways to do it, like Base64, Mime encoding etc.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Base64 is a good idea. So thanks, James Thorpe thanks for your comments

Comment: "worked properly" for character encodings, in my book, would be that an exception is thrown. So, `Encoding.GetEncoding(Encoding.Unicode.CodePage, EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback, DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback).GetString(data);`

Answer (score 5):

Converting an arbitrary, completely random byte array to a string by using an Text Encoding is not a good idea, since this only works, if the bytes actually represent a valid text, which is obviously not true, as your example shows.

Use Base64Encoding instead!

Convert.ToBase64String (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8f9a8s97(v=vs.110).aspx)
Convert.FromBase64String (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx)